# mouse keys not working

Tags: 18.04, mouse, reset

Version 18.04.3 right mouse key stopped working, I attempted to try and make the right key the primary key settings, devices. Now neither key works, if I left click on an icon in the favorites column a box appears with : new window, open a new window, remove from favorites and show details.

So currently there is no way to use the mouse. However if I left click on the desk top I can get to the terminal.

**My question is:**
Is there a way from the terminal to reset the the mouse settings to their original state?

Comment: Start xev and tell us what happens when you click on it with either button. How did you change the settings (screen capture with the current settings would help).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a workaround.

Before doing this, save all your work.

Open the System Monitor and end the process `Xorg`.